# what does this "a: ?number = null;" mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

In Facebook's [React Native's Geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) documentation I see this line of code:

```
 watchID: ?number = null;
```

I am clueless about it's nature. Is this even javascript?

Comment: There's a lot there that's *not Javascript*…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [Flow](https://flowtype.org/) typing meaning that variable `watchID` can be number or null.

Comment: so it's basically saying watchID is a nullable number? something like `int? watchID`

Comment: Btw, it's [Flow](https://flowtype.org/), not TypeScript. They're similar, though.

Comment: My bad, you are right, in TypeScript it would be `watchId?: number = null`. Thanks Dan!

Comment: Your answer is correct now but the code in your comment still wouldn't be valid TypeScript syntax. Without `--strictNullChecks`, any type is nullable (as in normal JS). With strict null checking enabled, you could use a union type, e.g. `watchId: number | null = null`.

Comment: You are right Tom, `watchId?` in TypeScript means that variable is optional.

Comment: @Mateusz yes, which would not make sense in this context - the fact that you're declaring the property means that it isn't optional. Normally the `?` is seen in interface declarations in TypeScript.

Comment: @Tom Correct :)